# Android Motion detection

Tags: android, android-sensors, motion-detection

I'm developing an app that should be launched when the phone is moved in a particular pattern, (even when the phone is screen locked / pattern locked) — say first horizontally, then vertically.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What you did related to this ?

Comment: http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html

Comment: The link given uses variation in the nearby objects to detect motion.. I rather need something which relies on sensors to detect motion..